# Best way to daemonize Java application on Linux

Tags: java, linux, daemon

While I found this question being answered here on SW several times, I didn't find a concluding answer what is the best approach.

I'm not looking to use any external wrapper, as I found them launching the java process under a nice level lower then themselves which potentially lowers the performance, so it seems only the shell methods are left.

I so far found 3 different shell methods:

- start-stop-daemon
- RedHat daemon init.d function
- nohup on start / disown after start

What you people are using, and can recommend as the most reliable method?

Thanks.

Comment: "What you people are using" polling questions are off topic for SO

Comment: "What you people are using" IS the topic, it is SO annoying that you people decide to just close things because they are "opinion based". Ironic isn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the standard answer to this seems to be [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html), I have been using djb's [daemon tools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) to be a great way to make anything into a daemon.

I have java, python and a few shell scripts all running as daemons, with a simple way to start/stop them and great logging.

I've used to run daemontools itself as root on initctl as originally designed, but after a few months I decided to run it manually, under a normal user, and using [svscan-start](http://thedjbway.b0llix.net/svscanboot.html) for nicer logging.

Answer (score 5):

If I want to run an application in the background as a daemon, I do it like this:

`nohup java -jar MyJar &`

There's nothing particularly unreliable about it - `nohup` keeps it from receiving a `SIGHUP` when you disconnect, and `&` runs a process in the background.

Optionally, you can redirect the output to something other than `nohup.out`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/. 
It's free and somewhat compatible reimplementation of TanukiSoftware Java Service Wrapper featuring free 64-bit support.

There is also a comparison table for [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/), [JSW](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/), [ACD](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/) and [L4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

I would use the RedHat daemon init.d function.  This allows you to have the application restart when the server does.  Running nohup doesn't handle server restarts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rule out the external wrappers completely.
I have noticed some well respected software using the Tanuki Wrapper http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/.

This has the added advantage that the program can also be easily run as a windows service, with a consistent approach.

Comment: He is not going to be able to run this as a Windows service on Linux.

Comment: Well I really haven't been watching mono developments all that closely, but that wasn't the point anyway. Why restrict the application to running on Linux only unnecessarily. Perhaps others may find the need to run the application and find themselves in a position where they can only run on windows. Rather than chase away potential users, why not limit restrictions and encourage re-use.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Akuma](https://akuma.dev.java.net/) in the past, with great success. The fact that it's a Java library really makes things easier, embedding the functionality is trivial.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using `screen` (Launch screen, then launch the java program, then close[not quit] the screen)

Comment: Not entirely a terrible suggestion, I do this for certain things. But I think this is pretty darn far from the intent of running something as a daemon. Still, thanks for the suggestion.