# Problem daemonizing Spring boot Java application with systemd

Tags: java, spring-boot, systemd

I would like to daemonize a Spring Boot Application. I read several articles and questions on how to do this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918629/cannot-start-systemd-service), [this](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/ubuntu-16-java-service-wrapper-example) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814222/how-to-write-a-java-daemon) for example but I can't get it to work.

Here is my step by step process:

1. First, I have created a sample Spring demo application that can be found [here](https://github.com/siddhsql/spring-demo-app) if needed. All it does is expose an endpoint that returns `Hello World`

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost.com:8080
Hello World
```

2. I created this `launcher.sh` bash script to launch the spring app according to the articles above:

```
#!/bin/bash
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/147530
SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )
# Specify the path to your Java application JAR file
APP_DIR="$SCRIPT_DIR/.."
echo "$APP_DIR"

start() {    
  # TODO: need to ensure that application is not already running
    cd $APP_DIR 
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814594/147530
    # redirect both input and output to the null device
    echo "starting spring boot application..."
  nohup mvn spring-boot:run < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &
  echo $! > demo-app.pid
}

stop() {
  cd $APP_DIR 
  PID=$(cat demo-app.pid)
  echo "stopping spring boot application PID: $PID"
  kill $PID
}

case $1 in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

3. Then I created following file in `/etc/systemd/system`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Spring Demo App
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/app/spring-demo-app/daemon/launcher.sh start
ExecStop=/app/spring-demo-app/daemon/launcher.sh stop
ExecReload=/app/spring-demo-app/daemon/launcher.sh restart
User=xxx
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. After that I performed the following steps:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable spring-demo.service
sudo systemctl start spring-demo
sudo systemctl status spring-demo
```

### Expected

service should start

### Observed

service does start but `systemd` immediately stops the service and puts it in failed state after repeating the cycle couple of times. here are the details:

1. see the [log](https://gist.github.com/siddhsql/61b7332649bcc2810be9129a9565875b) in `/var/log/syslog`. in the log observe:

```
2023-11-07T00:34:46.568688+00:00 instance-1 systemd[1]: Started spring-demo.service - Spring Demo App.
2023-11-07T00:34:46.575478+00:00 instance-1 launcher.sh[66104]: /app/spring-demo-app/daemon/..
2023-11-07T00:34:46.575982+00:00 instance-1 launcher.sh[66104]: starting spring boot application...
2023-11-07T00:34:46.586625+00:00 instance-1 launcher.sh[66108]: /app/spring-demo-app/daemon/..
2023-11-07T00:34:46.587937+00:00 instance-1 launcher.sh[66108]: stopping spring boot application PID: 66107
```

I have verified if I try to start the application using the command in `ExecStart` it works:

```
/app/spring-demo-app/daemon/launcher.sh start
```

the application starts although `echo $!` gave me empty output (this is not the main problem in this question)

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it? Been on this for a full day now.