# Java from /etc/rc.local

Tags: java

Is it possible to (safely) start a java program from /etc/rc.local? I'm using Ubuntu Nov. 2011 (Why should I learn what #s the months are?).

If it helps (and can improve specificity), I'm running Minecraft 1.2.5 Bukkit Server, and yes, I have a script preprepared that sets up every thing to start the server (RAM, nogui, set working dir, etc).

Comment: I think serverfault is a better place for this question.

Comment: Might depend on the program, whether it needs X up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, try to look at this answer for a generic Java process:

[Best way to daemonize Java application on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724725/best-way-to-daemonize-java-application-on-linux)

Then specifically for Minecraft you can read this [tutorial](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Startup_and_maintenance_script), and in particular this [chapter](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Startup_and_maintenance_script).

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial links; it seems I'm bad at reading the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Another approach is to create your own upstart script in `/etc/init.d/`. Take a look at `/etc/init.d/skeleton` and if it does make sense, make a copy of it and modify to suit your needs.